# Sql join when column is available else join with remaining columns?

Tags: sql, subquery, left-join

I want to left join table `T1` with `T2` on columns `a,b,c` .

I first try to join on all the three columns, but they don't join, so now as a fallback I join on columns `a,b`.

How do I implement this?

example

T1 :

```
+---+---+---+-------+
| a | b | c | mycol |
+---+---+---+-------+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | john  |
| 1 | 3 | 4 | cena  |
+---+---+---+-------+
```

T2:

```
+---+---+---+-------+
| a | b | c | value |
+---+---+---+-------+
| 1 | 2 | 3 |    10 |
| 1 | 3 |   |    20 |
+---+---+---+-------+
```

after join:

```
+---+---+---+-------+-------+
| a | b | c | mycol | value |
+---+---+---+-------+-------+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | john  |    10 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 | cena  |    20 |
+---+---+---+-------+-------+
```

Comment: what do you mean by "left join on columns"?? left join adds your columns anyway, it's inner join which only matches matching columns..? where are your columns a,b,c, in t1 or t2?

Comment: well, simply do select t1.a,t1.b,t1.c,t1.mycol,t2.value from t1 inner join t2 on t1.a=t2.a

Comment: @DevelJoe I don't get your comment, if I do simple left join, I'll get null in second row right

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: do your tables have the exact same amount of rows, t1 and t2, and will it stay like that? Then I suppose that the solution with aprimary key, or even unite t1 and t2 to one single table to avoid such future queries would be the best solution.

Comment: `(T1.a = T2.a) AND (T1.b = T2.b) AND ((T1.c = T2.c) OR (T2.c IS NULL))`

Comment: What DBMS are you asking this for? Please tag SQL requests always with the DBMS you are using. And please also tell us which version of that DBMS you are using. (In MySQL for instance it makes a great difference whether you use MySQL 8+ or an older version.)

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, you want two left joins and conditional logic

```
select t1.*, coalesce(t20.a, t21.a) a2, coalesce(t20.b, t21.b) b2, coalesce(t20.c, t21.c) c2
from t1
left join t2 t20 
    on t20.a = t1.a  and t20.b = t1.b and t20.c = t1.c
left join t2 t21
    on t20.a is null and t21.b = t1.b and t21.c = t1.c
```

The first left join attempts to match on the three columns. The second one joins on the first two columns only, and only when the first join came back empty. You can then use `coalesce()` in the `select` clause to bring the relevant value.

Comment: Hey can you please tell me what does `on t20.a is null` doing here.

Comment: @aroma: it allows the second join only when the first one did not succeed.

Comment: After checking first join failed, null a, the second join should be on a and b rather than on b and c

Comment: Also need to add a coalesce for `value`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.a, t1.b, t1.c, t1.mycol, t2.value
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.a=t2.a AND t1.b=t2.b;
```

other option to simply join all records based on t1:

```
SELECT t1.a, t1.b, t1.c, t1.mycol, t2.value
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.pk=t2.pk;
```

Comment: this would be incorrect as the join would add multiple rows in case 2 rows in T2 have a,b same and c different.

Comment: well then use the primary key to join; add a primary key column to tables 1 and 2 if not present and join them simply on t1.pk = t2.pk. I assumed that the combination of your a and b values was unique.

Comment: Actually, why don't you just do one table summing up both t1 and t2? making join statements for just one field seems weird and smells like bad DB design to me. Anyway, you may wanna consider the option with left join I printed above, I guess now I got what ya wanna do

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.*, coalesce(
         (select t20.value from t20 where t20.a = t1.a and t20.b = t1.b and t20.c = t1.c),
         (select t21.value from t21 where t21.a = t1.a and t21.b = t1.b )) as "value"
 from t1
```

For the second inner select you have to make sure it gets a unique result. So you may have to LIMIT the result to 1 but how to do this depends on your database of choice which you didn't mention.